# Suitescript print out object content

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

For debugging purposes, I want to see what's inside an object variable.  How can I print out an object content in Suitescript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can log the value of an object to the script log using the following:

```
// SuiteScript 1.0
nlapiLogExecution('debug', 'title', JSON.stringify(objectVariable));
```

or

```
// SuiteScript 2.0
log.debug('title', JSON.stringify(objectVariable));
```

Comment: In SuiteScript 2.0 it is not necessary to call JSON.stringify manually. It will be done automatically only if 1) a non String is passed and 2) the log level is high enough to actually log something. This is helpful for performance reasons, so that JSON.stringify is not running nested inside of log.debug calls, for example.